# Check if Grand Total is Negative

Tags: cart, grand-total

I need to refresh the cart page and show a custom block in case my Grand Totals is Negative.

```
$grandTotal = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

This prints `-$2,269.50`, but when I use the below condition, it just don't work.

```
If ($grandTotal < 0 ){
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}
```

How can I check if number is less than 0 i.e. negative

Thanks

Comment: why you want to refresh  page??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that getGrandTotal is returning a string rather then a number. Trying to see if a string is lower then 0 isn't going to work.

You can filter the string and remove anything which isn't a number using

```
filter_var($grandTotal, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Which in your case would return **-226950** which you can then check if it's lower then 0, if you need to do further checks you'll need to handle the way it removes the separator between the pounds and pence.

```
if(filter_var($price,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) < 0) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact amount as well, you can use

```
$currency_sign = "$";
$actual_amount = str_replace($currency_sign,'',$grandTotal); // $grandTotal is -$2,269.50
if($actual_amount < 0) { //$actual_amount will have the value as -2,269.50
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

all you need is to use the correct currency sign. You can get the current currency sign by the following code:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

Comment: Thanks for the currency code, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that
instead of  use

```
$grandTotal = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

please use

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];
```

it give proper integer/float value.